# Strange TextView behaviour in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, textview

**I have a detail page layout for actorin an an app. It contains an Info box with the most important information an biography and an recycler view with the movies the actor is playing in. However when the biography is quite short it looks that way:**

[image: Short Biography]

### **The margin between the header overview and the recycler view is quite small. However i never defined any margin and this margin even gets bigger when the biography becomes longer**

---

[image]

[image]

**It is not the fault of the custom TextView since the same strange behaviour occurs also with the normal TextView. Anyone an idea how to fix this strange behaviour ?**

Here is the xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/detail_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/detail_app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.CustomToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/movie_overview_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/detail_card_2_color"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin">


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/info_holder"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/overview"
                    >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/basic_info_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/detail_card_1_color"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
                        android:paddingLeft="56dp"
                        android:paddingRight="24dp">

                        <!-- Poster Area -->
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/poster_image_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                            <!-- Default Image -->
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/poster_image_default"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/default_poster"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.ThemeIcon
                                android:id="@+id/poster_image_def"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_alarm_white_48dp"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                custom:iconColor="?attr/icon_color"
                                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/poster_image_holder"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/detail_poster_width"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_poster_height"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin">

                                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/poster_image"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/detail_poster_width"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_poster_height"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:background="@color/default_image_background"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                                    />
                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <!-- Poster Image -->


                        </FrameLayout>

                        <!-- Text Area -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/poster_image_container"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <!-- Title -->
                            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                                android:id="@+id/cast_name"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_mobile_margin"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_subheading"
                                custom:robotoType="bold"
                                tools:text="01 January 2016\n120 mins" />

                            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                                android:id="@+id/cast_birthdy"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_layout_vertical_spacing_between_content_areas"
                                android:lines="1"

                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_subheading"
                                custom:robotoType="bold"
                                tools:text="01 January 2016\n120 mins" />


                            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                                android:id="@+id/cast_age"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_layout_vertical_spacing_between_content_areas"
                                android:lines="1"

                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_subheading"
                                custom:robotoType="bold"
                                tools:text="01 January 2016\n120 mins" />

                            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                                android:id="@+id/cast_homepage"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_layout_vertical_spacing_between_content_areas"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_subheading"
                                custom:robotoType="bold"
                                tools:text="01 January 2016\n120 mins" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.ThemeIcon
                    android:id="@+id/overview_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white_24dp"
                    app:iconColor="@color/accent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/overview"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/overview"/>

                <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                    android:id="@+id/overview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/detail_header_overview"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_holder"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/movie_overview_value"
                    custom:robotoType="bold" />


                <!-- Value -->
                <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                    android:id="@+id/movie_overview_value"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_body2"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/overview"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/info_holder"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/overview_icon"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sidescroll"
                    custom:robotoType="regular"
                    />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/sidescroll"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_overview_value"
                    />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.Coortextview-goes-behind-other-view-with-long-texts-constraintlayoutdinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Edit: This is no duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613994/textview-goes-behind-other-view-with-long-texts-constraintlayout since this question is about spacing behaviour and the other question is about why long text views hide behind another view while the short text text view doesnt

Comment: Check if you have wrong margins or padding values.

Comment: no I dont, sorry I forgot to add the xml file. Added it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView goes behind other view with long texts (ConstraintLayout)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613994/textview-goes-behind-other-view-with-long-texts-constraintlayout)

Comment: You need to add items one by one to layout what check which one is cousing this. Its very difficult to understand the problem by just reading code on you xml.

Comment: I tried it, the one causing the bug is movie_overview_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug does not exist with the most recent constraint layout version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `LinearLayout` to position the views, place this code below the `CardView` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.ThemeIcon
                android:id="@+id/overview_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_white_24dp"
                app:iconColor="@color/accent"
                />

            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                android:id="@+id/overview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/detail_header_overview"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                custom:robotoType="bold" />


            <!-- Value -->
            <com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.widget.TextViewRoboto
                android:id="@+id/movie_overview_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_body2"
                custom:robotoType="regular"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/sidescroll"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was able to do create an working layout with a relativelayout but since the release of the stable constraintlayout i want to do the same but with constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

I think this because you have just give anchor for the top most edge of the textview try to set anchor from top as well as bottom relative to the upper and lower view.

Comment: not sure what you mean excatly. Could you explain it a bit more detailed ?

Comment: When you will open your layout in design mode then select the text view then a rectangle you will see around that textview on the center of every edge of the rectangle you will see a circle just drag that to the upper view in same plane and do this same for the lower edge it will distribute the weight of textview relative to upper view  and lower view.

Comment: Now the views are completely invisible

Comment: try to see video on this page :-

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html